# How to set a header on excel page using apache POI?

Tags: excel, header, apache-poi

I have a header which I need to set on every page that is printed on a dynamic excel sheet.

Is there any way to get the page number ?

Comment: Can you not just use the same header string you'd set in Excel?

Comment: I need to generate this header automatically using apache POI. So I am looking for a function that gets me the page number in print setup so that when a new page comes, I can set the header.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `&P` like you would do in Excel?

Comment: It works thank you, but is there any way to set a header starting from 2nd page ?

Comment: HSSFHeader header = sheet.getHeader();//we can set contents for header

Answer (score 3):

As from [swamy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401439/need-to-set-a-header-on-excel-page-using-apache-poi#comment20163370_14401439) the solution is to get the [**`HSSFHeader`**](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFHeader.html) from the `HSSFSheet`

```
HSSFHeader header = sheet.getHeader();
```

Then you can set left, center and right text including font, font style, font size, page number, date, time etc.

**Example**

```
header.setCenter(HSSFHeader.font("Calibri", "regular") + 
       HSSFHeader.fontSize((short) 14) + "My " + HSSFHeader.startBold() + "Styled" + 
       HSSFHeader.endBold() + " Text with page number " + HSSFHeader.page());
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I used this to create header in my excel file, but when I open the excel file . The header is not visible , every time I have to click on header option in insert tab to see the content of header. do you have any solution so that I can enable header for the sheet , so that when I open the excel sheet I do not have to enable header from menu.